# iTextPDF 7 add text at absolute position

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I have an old Perl script that generates a .pdf file that can be printed on on perforated cards (like Avery template 28878). I am converting this script over to Java and have chosen to go with iTextPDF 7. So far I can generate the 10 "cards" without a problem (using absolute positions).

I am trying to add text to each "card" at an absolute position and set the font size of that text based on the width of a font size.

As for the font size part, I am doing the following in the old Perl script and it works pretty well with PDF::API2

```
# Font size 16 width = 184.832
$nameText->font($fonts->{'times'}, $nameFontSize);
while(int($nameText->advancewidth($name)) > 185){
    $nameFontSize--;
    $nameText->font($fonts->{'times'}, $nameFontSize);
}
```

For actually setting the absolute position, I do the following in Perl

```
my $nameText = $pdfPage->text();
$nameText->translate(($xCoord + 151), ($yCoord + 73));
$nameText->text_center($name);
```

I have not been able to figure out how to convert this to Java with iTextPDF 7.

So, how do I with iTextPDF 7
Set text to an absolute position?

Get the current width of that text object?

Comment: Please don't simply post Perl code but instead describe exactly what you want to do. iText is a Java/.Net library, iText users are not necessarily acquainted with Perl and in particular with PDF::API2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am giving you the code which is both very high level and low level. It is high level because it allows setting very high level properties like word/char spacing, justification, using complex scripts etc etc without modifying the approach to font size calculations. On the other hand it is low level because you will do a lot of manual layouting work which is typically done behind the scenes.

Please note that this is only one approach to what you are trying to achieve. I can think of at least two other ones. You can go and look for iText7 samples to look for inspiration.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("..."));
pdfDocument.addNewPage();
int pageNumber = 1;
PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber);

String text = "Hello World! This is an answer to a SO question";
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(text).
      setMargin(0).
      setMultipliedLeading(1).
      setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN));

float fontSize = 50;
paragraph.setFontSize(fontSize);
paragraph.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // Just to see that text is aligned correctly
float allowedWidth = 185;

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(page), pdfDocument, page.getMediaBox());
RootRenderer canvasRenderer = canvas.getRenderer();
while (paragraph.createRendererSubTree().setParent(canvasRenderer).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(pageNumber, new Rectangle(allowedWidth, fontSize * 2)))).getStatus() != LayoutResult.FULL) {
    paragraph.setFontSize(--fontSize);
}
float xCoord = 151;
float yCoord = 73;

paragraph.setWidth(allowedWidth);
canvas.showTextAligned(paragraph, xCoord, yCoord, TextAlignment.CENTER);
canvas.close();
pdfDocument.close();
```

This is how output looks:[image]
Note that we have added red background to see that text is centered.